# My 7-yrs old daughter asks the same questions everyday at the same time

Tags: primary-schooler

Questions like "you and mom were happy when I cried loud when I was born?" (because some day we've said that babies that born crying loud usually is considered a sign of good health) or "what's your favorite color besides blue?" (because the answer is yellow) and so on.

I understand that a 7-yrs old child likes this repetition thing (watching the same movie again and again and etc) and probably this is related to the way the brain is stimulated to "feel safe" when you get what you expect (which may be related to the way the brain does not like "frustration" which is not getting what you expect).

I'd just want to understand better why she asks the same question everyday at the same time. Obviously, she knows the answer, but I'd like to know if this is a normal process for this age, if this means she wants to check if some day we're going to give a different answer or if she just want to feel closer talking to me and my wife.

Comment: Are there other things she does on a "schedule", or is it just the asking thing? What does happen when you vary the answer?

Answer (score 3):

My son does this. He is 8 yo and has done this for years. He asks the same questions over and over even though he knows the answer. Sometimes we turn the question back on him and ask him the same question and he gives us the answer. He has been diagnosed with a progressing language impairment as well as ADHD so we believe that he is trying to process the world and by asking the same question. Does your child get "stuck" on other things? Our son gets stuck on certain thoughts which is part of his ADHD, related to obsessive compulsive characteristics but he has never been diagnosed with OCD. 
We try to be patient and explain things in different ways to help him process. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think ADHD also can be noticed in the school, which is not my case, I guess, but it's something to investigate, for sure. Thanks.